# add taxonomy term as an argument when there is a taxonomy filter

Tags: drupal

I have an Event node that can have a different "venue" taxonomy term, which are main,second, and third.

Currently, I have three Page Views that display the events based on the taxonomy filter for main, second, and third.

Now, I am including another taxonomy vocabulary to the Event node, which is the "season." So the user can input the taxonomy terms 2011 or 2012, etc...

Here is where I don't know what to do. I want to create a content type that will be limited to the creating of one node that will control which "season" will be displayed.

So under the three page views, if the user only chooses 2011, then only 2011 events under main, second, and third will be shown. If they choose both 2011 and 2012 then those seasons will be viewable.

Now, how would I connect my single node to my page views?

Is it possible to include two Term arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need a "season" exposed filter, no need to create a content type.